# Mostrar checbox ya marcados con jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo un fullcalendar y al dar clic en algún día me va a mostrar un formulario, el usuario ingresa los datos normal y debe seleccionar unas personas asignadas a ese evento con unos checkbox. (Ahí todo bien).

Imagen con  eventos creados: https://ibb.co/hgZpcK

Imagen del formulario de registro: https://ibb.co/huiXxK

El usuario al dar clic a un evento va a mostrar lo que el tiene en la base de datos:

Imagen del campo asignados en la base de datos: https://ibb.co/cMhWre

como pueden ver los asignados son: Julian Caicedo y Nelson Barrios, pero al dar clic en un evento siempre me muestra los dos primeros checkbox marcados osea, Andres Medina y Jhon Cortes y si en la base de datos tuviera un solo asignado ejemplo Nelson Barrios me mostraría el primer checbox que sería Andres Medina.

Imagen de un registro con datos de la base de datos: https://ibb.co/fuZQjz

Código donde tengo los checkbox:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12" id="formid">
    <label>Asignados:</label>
    <?php

    $contador = 1;

    foreach ($sql8 as $row){
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" <?php echo 'id="txtAsignados'.$contador.'"' ?> name="txtAsignados[]" class="txtAsignados" value="<?php echo $row['primer_nombre'] . " " . $row['primer_apellido']; $contador++; ?>"><?php echo $row['primer_nombre'] . " " . $row['primer_apellido']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

El contador lo que hace es concatenar con el id txtAsigandos para tener cada uno de los checkbox una ID diferente, ejemplo txtAsignados1, txtAsigandos2 y así dependiendo de la cantidad de asigados que existan.

El nombre de los asignados los saco directamente con una consulta en la base de datos:

```
$sql8 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT cedula, primer_nombre, primer_apellido, idrol FROM usuario WHERE idrol = 4 ORDER BY primer_nombre ASC");
```

Código Jquey para que marque los checkbox:

```
var contaAsig = 1;
var arrayAsig = 0;

    var texto = calEvent.asignados;
    separador = ",";
    textoseparado = texto.split(separador);

    for (;textoseparado[arrayAsig];){
    $('#txtAsignados'+contaAsig).prop('checked', true);
    contaAsig++;
    arrayAsig++;
}
```

Lo que necesito es que me marque los asignados que son y *NO* los primeros que son los que siempre chequea.

Comment: Pero es que el contaasig lo inicializas en uno y aumenta en el for osea siempre te va a marcar el checkbox txtAsignados1 y el que le sigue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicante hoy tienes un formulario con cuatro checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAsignados0" name="txtAsignados[]" class="txtAsignados" value="Andrés Medina">
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAsignados1" name="txtAsignados[]" class="txtAsignados" value="Jhon Cortes">
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAsignados2" name="txtAsignados[]" class="txtAsignados" value="Julian Caicedo">
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAsignados3" name="txtAsignados[]" class="txtAsignados" value="Nelson Barrios">
```

Y tienes un string con los nombres de las personas asignadas, concatenado por comas: `Julian Caicedo,Nelson Barrios`.

Tu lógica actual es:

- Exploto mi string usando la coma
- Me queda un array que contiene los nombres de dos seleccionados
- Uso la **posición** en el array para encontrar el checkbox

  - posición 0 => `jQuery('#txtAsignados0')`
  - posición 1 => `jQuery('#txtAsignados1')`

En otras palabras, con esa lógica siempre vas a chequear los primeros N checkboxes y eso no es lo que buscas.

Dada tu estructura actual, mi propuesta sería hacer en cambio:

- Exploto mi string usando la coma
- Me queda un array que contiene los nombres de dos seleccionados
- Uso el **valor** en el array para encontrar el checkbox que corresponde

  - Julian Caicedo=> `jQuery('.txtAsignados[value="Julian Caicedo"]')`
  - Nelson Barrios => `jQuery('.txtAsignados[value="Nelson Barrios"]')`

Acá un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
let seleccionados ='Julian Caicedo,Nelson Barrios'.split(',');

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  seleccionados.forEach(function(nombre) {
    jQuery(`.txtAsignados[value="${nombre}"]`).prop('checked',true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAsignados0" name="txtAsignados[]" class="txtAsignados" value="Andrés Medina">Andrés Medina
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAsignados1" name="txtAsignados[]" class="txtAsignados" value="Jhon Cortes">Jhon Cortes
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAsignados2" name="txtAsignados[]" class="txtAsignados" value="Julian Caicedo">Julian Caicedo
<input type="checkbox" id="txtAsignados3" name="txtAsignados[]" class="txtAsignados" value="Nelson Barrios">Nelson Barrios
```

Es ineficiente hacer que jQuery busque por el valor del checkbox. Sería mejor si en tu estructura guardases como "asignados" no la concatenación de los nombres sino, tal vez, la concatenación de algo que los hiciera únicos (por ejemplo su cédula) y usar ese campo a su vez en el ID de cada checkbox.

Asignándole un ID que es sólo un prefijo más un índice que se va incrementando, como haces hoy, no significa nada.

La manera correcta de hacer esto, sin embargo, es guardar una relación entre eventos y personas asignadas. Si hoy tienes la tabla `evento` (digamos que su PK es id_evento) y la tabla `usuario` (digamos que su PK es `cedula`).

podrías tener una tabla `evento_usuario` con la forma

```
id_evento | cedula
------------------
    1     | <cedula de Andrés>
    2     | <cedula de Jhon>
    7     | <cedula de Julian>
    7     | <cedula de Nelson>
```

De manera que no necesitas explotar un campo de texto, sino que puedes listar directamente los usuarios que están asignados al evento. Si además le pones una llave foránea a esta tabla de relación (y cláusula ON UPDATE CASCACE), incluso puedes obviar el caso de borde de querer cambiar la cédula de un usuario. La tabla de relación se actualiza en cascada con la nueva cédula.

Con la estructura que tienes hoy, si alguien edita el nombre de `Julian Caicedo` y le pone acento, perdiste todas sus asociaciones a eventos en donde figura con el nombre sin acento.

Comment: Si me sirvió, solo que hay un problema, digamos abro el primer evento y me chequea Nelson y Julian (Ahí esta bien), pero abro el segundo evento y los asignados son Nelson y Andrés, y me chequea Nelson y Andres, pero sigue chequeado Julian y el no está asignado a ese segundo evento, ¿Como solucionaría ese problema?

Comment: Cada vez que abras un evento, recorre todos los checbox y desmárcalos `jQuery('.txtAsignados').prop('checked',false);` antes de hacer match por nombre